# Incorrect URLs showing as extensions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am seeing this odd behavior in our Google Analytics reporting where page URLs end with the domain of sites we don't operate. For example, a page URL that should be costtodrive.com/florida-tolls is reported as costtodrive.com/florida-tolls/biography.com. This is inflating our sessions reporting. Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening here? I'm including screenshot with additional examples. Thanks!

[screenshot of additional url errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5iyM.jpg)

Comment: Did you set any regex with "starts with"? That might be the reason why it is getting both `/florida-tolls` and `/florida-tolls/biography,com`

Comment: not that I know of, but can check with developers. FYI I just added link to screenshot showing other errors after realizing this was missing on initial post

Answer (score 0):

This is GA spam almost for sure, and not any mistake you made. Look around the internet for guides for removing Google Analytics spam (hint: GA filters)